# Combo Box Selected Index -1 bound to Collection View Source

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I've a ComboBox Bound To a CollectionViewSource and I want that by default the selected index should be -1 (Because nothing should be selected) I've set SelectedIndex="-1"
and the first item is still selected. Why?

My View xaml:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="States" Source="{Binding States}"/>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Cities" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource States}, Path=Cities}"/>
</Window.Resources>


             <ComboBox  SelectedValue="{Binding Person.State}" Width="150"  SelectedValuePath="StateInitial"  DisplayMemberPath="StateName" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource States}}"/>
        <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Person.City}" Width="150" SelectedValuePath="CityId" DisplayMemberPath="CityName" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Cities}}"/>
```

Models c#

```
 public class State 
{
    public State(string stateInitial, string stateName, ICollection<City> cities)
    {
        StateInitial = stateInitial;
        StateName = stateName;
        Cities = cities;

    }

    public string StateInitial { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }



}
public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string CityName {get;set;}


}
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields
    private string state;
    private int city;
    #endregion

    public string State
    {
        get
        { 
            return state; 
        }
        set
        {
            state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("State");
        }

    }

    public int CityId
    {
        get
        {
            return city;
        }
        set
        {
            city = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("City");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        }
    }


}
```

ViewModel c#

```
   public  class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public Person NewPerson { get; set; }
    public List<State> States { get; private set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        States = GetStates();
        NewPerson = new Person();
    }
    public List<State> GetStates()
    {
        var stateList = new List<State>();
        var TaxesCities = new List<City>();
        TaxesCities.Add(new City(){ CityId = 1, CityName = "Dalles"});
        TaxesCities.Add(new City(){ CityId = 2, CityName = "Houstin"});
        stateList.Add(new State("TX", "Taxes" , TaxesCities));
        var NYCities = new List<City>();
        NYCities.Add(new City() { CityId = 3, CityName = "New York" });
        NYCities.Add(new City() { CityId = 4, CityName = "Brooklyn" });
        stateList.Add(new State("NY", "New York", NYCities));
        return stateList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using a CollectionViewSource which is automatically selecting the first element in the list because it can't find an entry for "null". Personally I don't think it's a good idea to use a CollectionViewSource in this case...you're already keeping track of the current state in Person.State so why do you need a CollectionViewSource to keep track of the current item as well? Also what happens if you have two ComboBox's on the same page? You'll need to create another CollectionViewSource so that they don't both share the same index. And finally any logic involving the UI (e.g. managing a currently selected item) should be done in the view model so that it can be tested.

There are a few problems with your code that need fixing, the first is the fact that you're binding yoru first ComboBox's SelectedValue to Person.State. There is no "Person" member of the main view model, I suspect you meant NewPerson, correct? Secondly the Person.State field is a string but your ComboBox is binding to a list of States, so when the user selects a state WPF will call that state's ToString() member and set that at the value i.e. your Person.State field will wind up with something like "YourProjectName.State". You can fix your binding to do this, but a better solution is to modify your Person class to reference State and City directly:

```
    private State state;
    public State State
    {
        get {return state;}
        set {state = value; OnPropertyChanged("State");}

    }

    private City city;
    public City City
    {
        get {return city;}
        set {city = value; OnPropertyChanged("City");}
    }
```

(Note there was a problem in your original City member...you'd changed it to CityId but you were doing OnPropertyChanged on "City").

Apart from being much better performance-wise you won't have problems with the combobox setting the intial state incorrectly, and if you fix up the other problems in your XAML bindings your master-view will now work properly as well:

```
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding NewPerson.State}" Width="150" DisplayMemberPath="StateName" ItemsSource="{Binding States}" />
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding NewPerson.City}" DisplayMemberPath="CityName" ItemsSource="{Binding NewPerson.State.Cities}" />
```

If you really do want your Person class to use the state name and city id then you should create a PersonViewModel that holds a reference to it and does the conversion. This is, after-all, how you should be structuring your data in MVVM...Person is really a model object.

Answer (score 0):

You're initializing SelectedIndex to -1 but then binding SelectedValue which is overwriting the initial selection. You have 3 options:

1. Get rid of SelectedIndex and set your initial SelectedValue to something that isn't in the list.
2. Bind SelectedIndex to an integer in your view model and set it to -1 at run-time once the bindings have been established.
3. Keep things as they are but set your SelectedValue's binding mode to OneWayToSource. This will prevent the binding from overwriting the initial value but it won't reflect any changes to SelectedIndex if you make them in the view model.

Comment: Thanks For your Response but option 1 and 3 didn't seem to work option 2 works but I think its a little messy

Comment: Odd, I tested both methods and in .NET 4.5 at least they worked fine. I'm guessing something else is interfering with the binding, any chance of posting a minimal example?

Comment: Thanks for responding I've edited the Question added more code In my scenario I've a list of dynamic data so adding a item should display "Please select One" is not an option

Comment: There seems to be a number of things wrong here, I think you might have to post your full code. If the list is dynamic then it needs to be an ObservableCollection, otherwise the front end won't get collection change notification. Also your ItemsSource binding seems to be wrong...it's a member of your view model but you're binding to it with StaticResource.

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear I've edited the code again  (by saying dynamic I meant that the data is from a database not like US states what is static data)

Comment: Sorry, there's too many errors in the code to give an answer at this point, it's impossible telling which ones are genuine errors and which (if any) are typos. Your first combo box is binding to a static resource called "State" but there's no static resource with that name. You have a CollectionViewSource with a name of "States" but that doesn't exist in your view model, did you mean "State"? And "Cities" tries to reference Path "Cities", but that doesn't exist in List<State>. I think you're getting a bit confused as to how bindings work, try posting an entire minimal example.

Comment: I've edited and Posted a Working Example, So please give a look. Sorry for the headache And thanks again