# WPF Combobox sorting, but initally no entry selected?

Tags: wpf, sorting, xaml, combobox, collectionviewsource

I implemented sorting for a WPF combobox using the following XAML:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedAreas" Source="{Binding AllAreas}">
  <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
  </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<ComboBox Name="PhotoLocationAreaComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedAreas}}"                
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
</ComboBox>
```

That works basically fine - the entries are sorted, but there is a side effect:

- Before I added the sorting (binding directly to AllAreas which is an ObservableCollection, internally no combobox entry was selected (empty)
- After the sorting, the first sorted entry is automatically pre-selected

Any idea how to restore the original behaviour (no entry selected) with the sorting? I tried SelectedIndex = "0", but that did not help.

Comment: check out [combo-box-selected-index-1-bound-to-collection-view-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638526/combo-box-selected-index-1-bound-to-collection-view-source)

Comment: SelectedIndex = -1  its not 0 for no entry, but i am not sure that fixes your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` property to `false`:

```
<ComboBox Name="PhotoLocationAreaComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedAreas}}"   
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
</ComboBox>
```